# RSA: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, rsa, out-of-memory

I am facing `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`
throwing from here : `com.rsa.certj.cert.AttributeValueAssertion.clone`

Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Can we see a little bit of the code that is causing the errors?

Comment: A full stack trace might also be helpful.

Comment: I mean by this question, does anyone encountered a JOOM in RSA code before, especially in this class?

Comment: This looks like a commercial library, so maybe you should get support from the company you bought it from.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out, what objects occupy your heap space. See [main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015264/main-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/2015461#2015461)